# How does Lagom Framework implement ES and CQRS (Scala)?

Tags: scala, microservices, cqrs, lagom

I'm fairly new to Lagom and trying to build my web project, I have already downloaded the sample projects given in the website (specifically Chirper & Auction),  but I've been stuck in ES and CQRS since a week, can someone share some knowledge, that you had, while working on it or even a sample project demonstrating it would really help. I have understood the lagom and microservice structure, but do not understand how ES and CQRS is implemented in it, like the Commands,Event Processors and the state. 
I'm sorry for being a little vague on the question I'm asking, but any developers who have worked in it, if could share some light, on how they started. Books, references and sample projects are highly welcomed.

p.s I have already gone through maybe 70% of the documentation in their official page, but a need a little more clarity.

Comment: The first question might be, do you have a good understanding of ES and CQRS? I will consider such a knowledge to be prerequisite if you want to then go on to understand how ES/CQRS is implemented in Lagoom.

Comment: Sorry for the self-promotion, but tried to answer your questions in a talk once, maybe that helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6_Nd7lu2PI

Answer (score 0):

`Command`s are requests for an entity to do something.  `Event`s are essentially notifications that something has happened (typically resulting from receiving a command, though not every command needs to result in an Event).  The `State` is the result of playing all the Events that have happened (in functional terms this is a fold over the history of Events), and the `EventHandler` is a [partial] function that, if defined for a particular combination of State and Event, creates a new State.